How do I rewrite the function without lambda?
Essententially, I want a list of objects, with attributes of (self, sym:'str', x: int, y: int), to sort alphabetically by the sym attribute. I would include the code, but the above is an imported class and very lengthy. The following line works, but I am trying to rewrite it without lamda.
self.list= sorted(self.list, key=lambda list:list.symbol)
I've tried using a get_sym function for the key from that class, but I get syntax errors. I am not very familiar with using sorted without lamba. I've looked online for similar questions, but I'm not very familiar with anything beyond using a get_item function already established in the class. Any help is appreciated.

"I am trying to rewrite it without lamda." Why? this is like asking I'm trying to add numbers without using +? [ask]

The assignment I'm doing asks for it. I've referred to Python documentation, and I haven't found much other than using lambda.

@Julien - I don't agree - it could maybe be likened to multiplying without using x though

Just write a named function rather than an anonymous function (lambda). Also if the attribute is sym then list.symbol isn't going to work

@SiHa not really, if you prefer not using convenient shortcuts you can decide to use operator.add rather than +...

if you get error message when you use get_sym then maybe show this error instead of asking how to do it without lambda

As an alternative to a named function, you can use operator.attrgetter:
self.list = sorted(self.list, key=operator.attrgetter('symbol'))


The key argument of sorted accepts any callable which takes one argument. A lambda is just a very compact way of defining such a callable. You can also define a function and use that:
def get_sym(obj):
    return obj.sym

self.list = sorted(self.list, key=get_sym)

Note that you can also use self.list.sort(key=get_sym) to sort the list in-place (assuming that self.list is of type list)
